# How to export constant field to swagger ui?

Tags: java, swagger

I want to export the constant key to swagger-ui. Is there any solution?

```
public interface DictKeyConstant {

    String SELECT_HOUSE_TYPE_KEY = "select_house_type";

    String HOUSE_CERTIFICATE_PREFIX_KEY = "house_certificate_prefix";

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "export"? What exactly do you want the swagger-ui to do with the constant keys?

Comment: Do you use springfox or do you have the swagger-ui source code in your code base?